# Is List.Foreach(Delegate) implemented in Mono?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, monodevelop

I'm using MonoDevelop 2.4 in Ubuntu 10.10 and I can't seem to do a simple C# call.

```
myList.DGraph.ForEach(delegate(string s){Console.WriteLine(s)});
```

I receive this as an error:

```
DirectedGraph.cs(219,78): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `}'
DirectedGraph.cs(250,1): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `}', expecting `)', or `,'
DirectedGraph.cs(251,1): error CS8025: Parsing error
```

It doesn't seem to like this, although as far as I can tell, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) [is](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/447223-foreach-list-foreach) [valid](http://www.willasrari.com/blog/listforeach-method--delegate-trick/000206.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a semicolon (`;`)

```
myList.DGraph.ForEach(delegate(string s){Console.WriteLine(s);});
                                                             ^
```

otherwise that is not a legal method body.